# GIMP 2.10: PDF Export: How to export each layer GROUP as a new page?

Tags: gimp, pdf, export, page-layout

GIMP can export each `layer` as a new page[*]… but is there a way to do it based on `group layers` instead?

**Alternative trick:** Flatten each layer group before printing using `Merge Layer Group`… without saving the file!

[*] See how on [How can I export a PDF from GIMP with each layer on a new page?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098603/17228)

Comment: Well, there's a [feature request for that](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/5235), from 15 June 2020.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.  You should have posted it as an answer, then you could choose it as best answer.

Comment: @Billy, well I don't consider the alternative trick as a solution  The real solution may come from the open feature request…